# Why does rotating a SCNCameraNode with M_Pi_2 point it straight down?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I made an SCNCamera and want it to be pointed straight down at the floor. I used this code: `camera.rotation = SCNVector4Make(-1, 0, 0, Float(M_PI_2))`

Why does this code make it point at the floor? How does pi have anything to do with it? I am very confused as to what is going on here. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain it.

Comment: It's all about trigonometry. See [Rotation by radians and quadrants](http://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/unit-circle-trig-func/radians_tutorial/v/rotation-by-radians-and-quadrants)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist what does the w parameter mean in SCNVector4Make?

Comment: from the documentation: The four-component rotation vector specifies the direction of the rotation axis in the first three components and the angle of rotation (in radians) in the fourth.